# Running SVD in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, svd

I have a RDD in which i have word and it's vector representation. I followed following example:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html

The SingularValueDecomposition class returns the RowMatrix. It doesn't have word for which the vector was originally  generated in RowMatrix. I am not getting how to use SingularValueDecomposition output now since it is just reduced matrix with no word label in it.

Anyone faced the similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do by following below steps:

```
// GET word and vector.
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new  CountVectorizer().setInputCol("filteredWords").setOutputCol("features").setVocabSize(100000).setMinDF(2).fit(newSentenceData)
// Model is fitted
val fittedModel = cvModel.transform(newSentenceData)

// Converted the Dataframe to RDD as the SVD library works on RDD.
val rddVectorWithAllColumns = fittedModel.rdd

// Here, i have truncated the code and assumed that svd variable is holding the model. In this step, i am accessing the U matrix and adding the word back to the RDD so that we can get reduced vectors and word.
val test = svd.U.rows.map(row => row.toArray).zip(rddVectorWithAllColumns.map(row => row.getString(0))).map(line => line._2 + "\t" + line._1.mkString("\t"))
```